# Gradle Build Errors?

Tags: android, gradle, build

I've been having a gradle build error with my android application. I have the following structure of my code:

```
app
   manifests
   java
      package.myApp
          ApplicationTest.java
      package.myApp.interfaces
          map
             DefaultMap.java
          sidelists
          welcomescreen
   res
      layout
      mipmap
      values
```

The following AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package.myApp" >

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".interfaces.map.DefaultMap"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map__default">
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the following build.gradle for the module: app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "oose2017.place2b"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

For some reason, the project appears to have issues building. In the background tasks at the bottom, the notifications shows 'gradle build running' for the last 15 minutes, and it appears to be hung up on (note that this was started 8 minutes ago as it is now 5:55):

```
5:46:43 PM Gradle sync started
5:47:05 PM Gradle sync completed
5:47:06 PM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]
```

as the most recent line that it will display after saying gradle sync completed just above that. I am not sure if this has to do with the same issue, however, in DefaultMap.java, I am receiving the error:

```
cannot resolve symbol, 'R'
```

What can I do to resolve this issue? The project will not even build properly, and I am sure it is a simple error. I have not really edited anything since instantiating the default project from android-studio in terms of the xml, other than adding the line for the notitlebar, in the androidmanifest, and the only thing I tried changing in the build.gradle was upping the sdk from 21 to to 23. Anybody have any suggestions? I've tried rebuilding, closing the project and reimporting, invalidating caches and restarting, which were the primary things i could find searching previous people who encountered this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try make the project and Clean the project and then rebuild again

Answer (score 0):

R errors usually occur when one of your XML files is corrupt. Sometimes unnoticeable!

1) Try importing `R.java` in your `DefaultMap.java`

2) `Clean Project -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

if that doesn't work, see what is causing problem with `R.java` import. Make sure you import the required `R class` which references to the one you need.